Metodo POST con Retrofit2 y Jetpack - Jetpack Compose
Estoy iniciando en android y el metodo post con la libreria retrofit me causo muchos problemas e modificado mi codigo muchas veces sin lograr solocionar el problema, tratando de hacerlo lo mas simple posible pero aun asi siempre me sale el mismo error :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dgs.pruebabase, PID: 26082
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setStrictness(Strictness.LENIENT) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
See https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#malformed-json
Me podran recomendar como poder investigar el problema o donde podria ver similar para poder orientarme. gracias
Con el metodo Get no tuve problemas. Mientras que con el post e verificado mi codigo muchas veces sin solucion.
La api es local y desde postman e podido realizar todas las operaciones sin problema, mientras que desde la app al presionar el boton se cierra y sale el error en el el Logcat.

